# How to wait until my thread is finished

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

```
private void showStatistics(string path)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Statistics myClass= new Statistics(path);
            list = myClass.getStatistics();
        });

    thread.Start();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in list )
    {
        listBoxIps.Items.Add(item.Key + item.Value + "\n");
    }
}
```

I want to wait until thread has finish its job and then start the `foreach`, when I put the `foreach` in the thread, cross threading error received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [thread.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332368%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). But that's probably not exactly what you are trying to do (because Join will block, in which case why even use a separate thread in the first place). Look into the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx%20BackgroundWorker) class.

Comment: Also, look into and understand Form.Invoke.  You can have your thread, at its completion, call a method in your form, but it must do it using Invoke... if your ' after thread logic' does anything with any Controls.

Answer (score 1):

To wait for the `Thread` to complete you can use the `Join` API.  However that's likely not what you want in this scenario.  A `Join` here would cause the entire UI to block until the `Thread` completed which would defeat the purpose of having the thread in the first place.

An alternate design is to spawn of the `Thread` and have it call back into the UI once it's complete via `BeginInvoke`.  Assuming `getStatistics` returns a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>`.

```
private void showStatistics(string path) {
  Action<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> action = list => {
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in list ) {
      listBoxIps.Items.Add(item.Key + item.Value + "\n");
    }
  };

  Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
    Statistics myClass= new Statistics(path);
    list = myClass.getStatistics();
    this.BeginInvoke(action, list);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create shared variable, and use it to signal finish of the thread.  In the loop, after thread is started, do:

```
while (!finished)
{
     Application.DoEvents();
     Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

Your problem is that you want your UI to be responsive while `list` is filled.  That will ensure it.